# Special characters being added to linux file

Tags: linux, filesystems, corruption

In one of my box, I see special characters being added to "/etc/hosts" file. Not sure what is causing this. Any idea on how to debug this ?

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@127.0.1.1    linux-host
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `lsof` command to see what process opens the file.
For example:

```
$ sudo lsof /bin/ping
COMMAND  PID USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
ping    4216 amit txt    REG    8,1    64424 1048708 /bin/ping
```

It will be trickier to catch it if the process doesn't keep the `fd` of the file open though...